# Delete tag and blackhole - slowness

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/slowness

Please kill it with fire. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only 6 questions tagged `slowness` I have retagged them all. The tag can be deleted now.